# How do you define and draw rectangles in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am very new to OpenGL and I am not sure one the basis of how to create and draw objects. So how would I draw simple rectangles in a window using OpenGL? My understanding is that I need to define an array of vertices like

type name[n] = {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};

but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

How do I used glBegin(what goes here) to draw a rectangle using this?

Thanks.

Edit 2: We are using OpenGL 2.6 or 2.7 for my class so can't use stuff from 3.0+. Also using C++ on windows

Edit: Why does this now draw 4 vertices? I know this function is supposed to work because it is from an example. It prints points but when I change it it won't draw the 4 vertices I define.

Edit: Uploaded all code I am working with.

```
void myinit(void)
{   /* attributes */

      glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); /* white background */
      glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); /* draw in red */

/* set up viewing */
/* 500 x 500 window with origin lower left */

      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 0.0, 500.0);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void display( void )
{      
    GLfloat rect[4][3] = { {0.0,0.0, 0.0}, { 500.0,0.0, 0.0 }, { 500.0,500.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0,500.0, 0.0 } };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  /*clear the window */

          glBegin(GL_POINTS);
               glVertex3fv(rect); 
          glEnd();
     glFlush(); /* clear buffers */
 }


void main(int argc, char** argv)
{

/* Standard GLUT initialization */

    glutInit(&argc,argv);

/* default, not needed */
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);    

    glutInitWindowSize(500,500); /* 500 x 500 pixel window */

    /* place window top left on display */
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);    

    glutCreateWindow("Sierpinski Gasket"); /* window title */

    /* display callback invoked when window opened */
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 

    myinit(); /* set attributes */

    glutMainLoop(); /* enter event loop */
}
```

Edit: I was actually painting something the entire time but it was too small to see. Once I changed the point size with glpointsize() I was able to see it.

Comment: Have you tried Google? https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides

Comment: I read the chapters in my text book that is supposed to cover the material for this but I can't get the rectangles to draw. I have 
void display( void )
{      
 GLfloat rect[4][3] = { {0.0,0.0, 0.0}, { 500.0,0.0, 0.0 }, { 500.0,500.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0,500.0, 0.0 } };

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  /*clear the window */

          glBegin(GL_POINTS);
               glVertex3fv(rect); 
          glEnd();
     glFlush(); /* clear buffers */
 }

and it won't draw it to the window.

Comment: You need to set the different matrices up before doing something on the screen.

Comment: Also, if you need quads, and ypu have 4 vertices then (I can't believe I'm saying this) change GL_POINTS to GL_QUADS. Also, if your class uses openGL 2.*, then you shpuld leave that class. It's outdated, most of the computers support OpenGL 3 or up.

Comment: @Bálint I uploaded the full code. The main function and the init function are untouched from a book example but still shows nothing.

Comment: As I thought, you meysed up the gluOrtho2D call, you need to do gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 500.0, 0.1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this, I mention here the 2 most popular one, so vertex array objects and immediate mode.

To draw a rectange on the scree with immediate mode, you need to do the following:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
glEnd();
```

*Note: For some languages (like java) if you write a floating point number, you get a double instead of a float, so you need to give a suffix to it, like 0.5f*

*Note2: Don't use GL_QUADS, it is deprecated, because it makes things harder for the GPU*

This is the easiest method for drawing simple things, however, because you do a lot of native API calls, it is really slow compared to other techniques. Instead, if possible, and you GPU allows it, use `Vertex array objects`.

This can make your game even faster, if you have multiple of the same model, like a 2d plane for sprites, different tree models, etc. In these cases, you only need to bind the vertexArray once, then render different objects at different location, with different attributes, it depends on **you** what you do with it.

Sadly, this topic is too in-depth for this post, and because I don't even know what language you're using, I can't even link a tutorial. Google it.

Comment: If he is new to the language, it might help to avoid the fixed pipeline, and start right away with the shader approach. `gl_begin` is no longer current. Consider googling a modern (AKA 3.0+) OpenGl tutorial

Comment: I actually started, to explain it, but because there are many differences between different implementations, and a lot of language has an opengl library, like java (LWJGL, JOGL), c++, even lua, I couldn't do too much.

Comment: True, GL_QUADS is deprecated, but so is the whole fixed pipeline.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine GL_QUADS is not part of the fixed pipeline. It can be used with both glDrawArrays and glDrawElements, and also with their instanced version (and with the many many ways opengl allows you to render stuff). It's deprecated, because it is less efficient, than a GL_QUADS. A GPU can't render quads, it can only render triangles, so before it can render the quad, it needs to proccess it, so it is 2 triangles instead. SO rendering 2 triangles is still faster for the GPU, than 1 QUAD.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to clear everything - because you are a newbie you can use `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`

After that it's time to "set" your "background" color like this:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 255.0f);
```

You can put your own RGB color here.

And finally draw simple quad.

And after that you have to update your screen, the way to do that depends on which library you are using for windowing.

So here is the final code:

```
float r = 0.0f; //RED
float g = 0.0f; //GREEN
float b = 0.0f; //BLUE

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(r, g, b, 255.0f);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); //You can set RGB color for you vertex
glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
glEnd();

//UPDATE THE SCREEN
```

Edit:

For now you can keep using [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) but in the future I suggest you to learn shaders.

You can read about OpenGL's rendering pipeline here: [Rendering Pipeline](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)

Comment: 1.: glClearColor comes **before** glClear for obvious reasons
2.: Don't ever use GL_QUADS, it's deprecated for a reason.
3.: I already posted the solution, why do you need to do it too?

Comment: I know it's deprecated, but I wanted to show him another way to do it. He's beginner so at this moment he can use it.